# How to combine these three sql queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

How to combine these two sql queries into one?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rss WHERE MATCH(content,title) AGAINST ('$filter') 

SELECT COUNT(content) FROM rss WHERE MATCH(content,title) AGAINST ('$filters')
```

And if the result is 0 from the above query

-

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rss WHERE content LIKE '%$filters%' OR title LIKE '%$filters%'; 
$filter .= $row['filter'];
$filters = $row['filter'];
```

$filters may be more than one keyword

Comment: Because match...against is more accurate but it doesn't return anything when searching a common word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use query 2,

[`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) will indicate how many rows for query 1, so just discard query 2

if `mysql_num_rows` return zero, then proceed with query 3

To combine three queries into one, use `OR`

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rss 
WHERE 
  (MATCH(content,title) AGAINST ('$filter'))
OR
  (content LIKE '%$filter%' OR title LIKE '%$filter%')
```

As explained above, you do not really need to do count first.

If $filter contains lots of keyword, then just repeating like

```
  (content LIKE '%$filter_1%' OR title LIKE '%$filter_1%') OR
  (content LIKE '%$filter_2%' OR title LIKE '%$filter_2%') OR ...
```

Comment: Yes I did that ,it returns me again repeating results?

Comment: Is either your data contains repeat records, **OR**, you method for output is wrong. You should update your question will your table schema, sample data that you think is repeated, and of course, your full code for this (not the entire, but the portion doing this)

Comment: Good solution, 2 queries against the same table is just meninsløst when you only have a data set. +1. I would have maybe added a solution without **OR**, because of the execution plan, if you have indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine 1 and 3 using `UNION ALL`. But you can't merge 2nd with other 2, because `COUNT` returns aggregate for a bunch of rows.

You are better off writing a stored procedure in your case, than trying to stuff in all three into a single statement.

EDIT (via sv88erik): Since you are using `UNION ALL`, you don't need a `DISTINCT` keyword in each query.

Comment: UNION ALL, then you do not need to have DISTINCT